# Quebrar linha em uma Cell da classe FPDF do PHP?

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

Gostaria de saber como posso inserir uma quebra de linha com o `FPDF` do `PHP`.
Estou colocando o seguinte código:

```
$pdf->Cell(0,20, "Declaramos que ".$nome.$quebra_linha." participou da I SAEP - Semana Acadêmica \n de Engenharia de Produção....",0,0,'L');
```

mas a continuação da linha continua na primeira linha e sai do `PDF`.
Inserir uma outra `Cell` abaixo da primeira, com a continuação do texto também é uma opção, mas não estou conseguindo fazer.

Answer (score 2):

Para quebra de linha o *comando* [***MultiCell***](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/multicell.htm):

> `MultiCell(float w, float h, string txt [, mixed border [, string align [, boolean fill]]])`

```
$pdf->MultiCell(0, 20, $texto,0,'L', false);
```

*Veja configurações detalhadas no* [**link**](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/multicell.htm).

[***Manual***](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/index.php) do `FPDF`

Answer (score -2):

Para quebra de linha o comando MultiCell:

```
MultiCell(float w, float h, string txt [, mixed border [, string align [, boolean fill]]])
$pdf->MultiCell(0, 20, $texto,0,'L', false);"
```

Answer (score -2):

Usa o comando MultiCell. Irá quebrar a linha quando a width do conteúdo ultrapassar o parâmetro “w” passado a esta função.